# dejar solo 2 teclas en teclado

Tags: android-studio

hola he intentado poner el teclado para que solo aparezcan el 0 y el 1 pero al parecer solo me pone el teclado numérico, podría alguien decirme como dejar solo esos 2 números?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/binario1"
                    android:layout_width="146dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/title_home"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    tools:targetApi="o" />
```

Comment: Y si mejor creas una función donde al dar click a un textView aparezca como que un teclado, donde vos creas 2 botones, que seria el 0 y el 1. Y al dar click a esos botones agregen al textview

Comment: no lo había pensado de esa manera amigo o probare.